# VirtualBox 4.3.20 stops working after Windows Update

Tags: windows-7, virtualbox, windows-update

I have a current version of VirtualBox 4.3.20, but after the latest Windows 7 update on Dec. 11th, 2014, it cannot open any virtual machine. First, it would not open the program at all. After a reboot, it would say:

[image]

> STATUS_OBJECT_NAME_NOT_FOUND
>
> Driver is probably stuck stopping/starting. Try 'sc.exe query vboxdrv' to get more information about its state. Rebooting may actually help. (rc=-101)

The log file says:

```
b28.146c: supR3HardenedVmProcessInit: Opening vboxdrv stub...
b28.146c: Error opening VBoxDrvStub:  STATUS_OBJECT_NAME_NOT_FOUND
b28.146c: supR3HardenedWinReadErrorInfoDevice: NtCreateFile -> 0xc0000034
b28.146c: Error -101 in supR3HardenedWinReSpawn! (enmWhat=3)
b28.146c: NtCreateFile(\Device\VBoxDrvStub) failed: 0xc0000034 STATUS_OBJECT_NAME_NOT_FOUND (0 retries)
```

I've tried installing an older version (4.3.18) as well, reinstalling the current version several times, rebooting, uninstalling antivirus software, but nothing helped.

Comment: You may get the same error on a bad virtualbox upgrade (e.g. left it running when upgrading). Try `sc start vboxdrv` and if that fails find `C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\drivers\vboxdrv\VBoxDrv.inf` right click and select `Install` and try again

Comment: The comment above was the solution for me.

Comment: The comment above was the solution for me too.

Comment: same here. I just did on cmd `sc start vboxdrv` and now I can use my VM. Make sure to run cmd as administrator, otherwise it won't work. thank you @KCD you saved me

Comment: @KCD's solution worked for me as well, should make a post with it instead of just a comment.

Comment: @KCD's answer worked for me too; they should add it as an answer and I'll upvote.

Comment: @KCD anwser helped me too, IMHO not a duplicate of the KB3004394 thread

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have to remove the Windows Update KB3004394 (or install [this update](http://support2.microsoft.com/kb/3024777/en-us), which apparently just removes the old one). The whole procedure is [explained here](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/remove-update#1TC=windows-7).

After uninstalling that update, also uninstall VirtualBox, restart, then install VirtualBox, restart again.

Apparently [others have had this issue too](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=64777&start=60). The update seems non-critical and should cause no security issues when removed:

> The Windows Root Certificate Program enables trusted root certificates to be distributed automatically in Windows. Usually, a client computer polls root certificate updates once a week. After you apply this update, the client computer can receive urgent root certificate updates within 24 hours.

For others, the problem may be caused by using custom themes (i.e. with a patched theme DLL). This could be fixed by running `sfc /scannow`, but it did not apply in my case.